# How to replace newline with backspace and replace " " with a ' ' in a text file using sed in Linux?

Tags: bash, sed

This is my text file :

```
  "id",
  "isActive",
  "firstName",
  "lastName",
  "jobTitle",
  "email"
```

Expected output :

```
'id','isActive','firstName','lastName','jobTitle','email'
```

Comment: What about the leading spaces?

Comment: ^ and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have no idea how to use sed command..and there are no leading spaces ..there are just newlines

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -z "s/[ ]*\\\"/\\'/g;s/\n//g" input.txt > out.txt
```

The first `sed` script (`s/[ ]*\\\"/\\'/g`) strips the leading spaces and replaces the double quotes with single. The second (`s/\n//g`) deletes all of the newlines.

The `-z` flag switches `sed`'s delimiter from the newline to the null terminator, allowing us to see the newlines in the stream. The downside of this is that the whole input file is read into memory. If you have a large input file, this may not be an option.

Sources & in-depth explanation:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/1125280/892469
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/384775/311383

Comment: Assuming GNU `sed`